# Can a class initialize its non-immediate base classes in its member initialization list?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, initialization, derived-class

The following code is excerpted from [Apache C++ Standard Library User's Guide](http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibug/39-3.html)

```
class DerivedOutputStream : public std::ostream {
  public:
    DerivedOutputStream():
      std::ios(0), std::ostream(&dsb) {}        //1
    // ...
  private:
    DerivedStreamBuf dsb;
    // ...
};
```

---

Please note that `std::ios` is not the immediate base class of `DerivedOutputStream`, but it appears in the member initialization list.

I think that is not correct, is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is correct if it is a virtual base class. Virtual bases are initialized from the most derived class.

Comment: It probably is, based on the following diagram: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io